# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BINARY HIBERNATE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I get  ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BINARY  when im trying to execute a JQPL which has TO_TIMESTAMP in the query.
productDate is being passed as null to the menthod. ( This is not the
complete query)

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Products products " 
        + " AND (:productDate IS NULL OR header.productDate <= TO_TIMESTAMP(:productDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') )" 
int getProductsCountByDate(@Param("productDate") String productDate)
```

When I replace `:productDate` inside `TO_TIMESTAMP` with a empty value(''), it does not give the error. What I understand is when productDate is null, the application gives the above exception. Any clue to fix the error would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use db functions in jpql. Convert the values inside of your application to the correct type

Comment: Hi @Jens, thanks for your reply. any particular reason for that ?

Comment: As you can see in your example, it is much easier to control the conversation in java than in sql. Also I am not sure if this function is sql standard and works on all rdbms

Comment: Yeah understand. We are using oracle DB, and this works in another project. Im not sure why it does not work in my project.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jen mentioned, its better doing data conversion at java code level. However my issue was passing null instead of empty to TO_TIMESTAMP function.